# What is !pip (bang pip)?

Tags: python, pip

I came across [that answer which seem to have pleased 3 people](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61847103/7054798) and before importing the nest_asyncio package it was doing that :

```py
!pip install nest_asyncio
```

is that a correct syntax? it looks neat if it works (it didn't for me). If it works, is there a reason not to use it more?

Comment: Are you trying through cmd to install that module

Comment: `!pip` is used in jupyter notebooks to install python modules/packages. You can use just `pip` if you are installing packages via command line.

Comment: Do you look for this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41510454/why-does-pip-need-an-exclamation-point-to-use-in-ipython)?